# how to implement this overlay with flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, cross-platform

[image]

how to implement this overlay with flutter? notice the triangle shape in the position of the button.

Comment: try OverlayPortal

Answer (score 0):

i used stack with render box offset. with two children inside stack on child for traingle shape and one for big white box.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can use the paint widget for the same and later using the positioned widget you can place it on top of any container .

below is the example code to us  the paint widget

```
 class TriangleBox extends CustomPainter {
    final Color strokeColor;
    final PaintingStyle paintingStyle;
    final double strokeWidth;

    TrianglePainter({
     required this.strokeColor,
     required this.paintingStyle,
     required this.strokeWidth,
    });

    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = strokeColor
      ..style = paintingStyle
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;

    final Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.close();

     canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
     }
  }
```